# (Rails) When to use ActiveRecord's .where and .select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Model in my Rails app named `User`, which has an attribute `name`

Let's say I want to find all `Users` whose `name` matches a specific string.

In a Rails Console, I could do:

OPTION 1

`User.where("name LIKE 'string'")`

This is very fast.

OPTION 2

`User.select{|u| u.name == "string"}`

This is extremely slow. It works for a small database, but if you have hundreds of thousands of users, this appears to try to load all `Users` into memory first, and then iterate them in the block.

Does this mean that option 2 is always wrong ? What's the correct use case for `.select` then, when is it preferable over `.where` ?

I wrote a bunch of code in my app that is working fine using `.select`, but now that I tried using over a very large table I saw that I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Select: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

"This will build an array of objects from the database for the scope, converting them into an array and iterating through them using Array#select."

So, it's so slow because it fetches EVERYTHING from the database, converts them to Ruby objects one by one, then runs the block you give on them. If you've got a database table with 100,000 rows, that means instantiating 100,000 ruby objects and running your block on them. Ruby is slow, so this is slow.

Using `where` will basically just put together an SQL statement, and let the database handle it. Databases are FAST - if speed is a priority, then whenever you can defer to the database, you should do so. If you have a database table with 100,000 rows, but only 10 match your `where` query, then the database will handle the filtering, and Ruby will only receive 10 rows back and will therefore only have to instantiate 10 Ruby objects, not 100,000.

Almost always, you'll want to use `where` rather than `select`. So, when might you use select? Well you'd use it (often in conjunction with `where`) when you want to filter a relatively small number of records based on some ruby conditions that would be reasonably hard to translate to SQL.

Example:

```
User.where(account_cancelled: true).select do |u|
  # perform complex ruby logic on user 
  # that would be hard to do with plain SQL
  # (note, this will only act on the subset of 
  # users returned from the where clause)
end
```

So, whenever you reasonably can use `where` rather than `select`, you should do so.

(there's also a second use of `select` mentioned in the documentation: "Modifies the SELECT statement for the query so that only certain fields are retrieve" - but that's not the use you're dealing with in your question)

Comment: Rails 4 added the .find_by method which is essentially the same as where - it's worth reading the Rails style guide which gives more detail on it's most accepted usage - https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#find_by

Comment: @BenHawker Just to avoid any confusion for someone passing through, 'find_by' only returns the first record found for a particular pattern, whereas 'where' returns all of the records matching a pattern. 'find_by' leverages 'where' to pattern match, then just takes the first value found. 
[For Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by-21)